# Tarantool module installation failed searching manifest

Tags: tarantool

I am trying to install tarantool module. Tatrantool run in docker container with image tarantool/tarantool:2.3.

```
/opt/tarantool # tarantoolctl rocks install prometheus
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://rocks.tarantool.org/ - Failed downloading http://rocks.tarantool.org/manifest - /root/.cache/luarocks/http___rocks.tarantool.org_/manifest
prometheus not found for Lua 5.1.
Checking if available for other Lua versions...
Checking for Lua 5.2...
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://rocks.tarantool.org/ - Failed downloading http://rocks.tarantool.org/manifest - /root/.cache/luarocks/http___rocks.tarantool.org_/manifest
Checking for Lua 5.3...
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://rocks.tarantool.org/ - Failed downloading http://rocks.tarantool.org/manifest - /root/.cache/luarocks/http___rocks.tarantool.org_/manifest
Checking for Lua 5.4...
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://rocks.tarantool.org/ - Failed downloading http://rocks.tarantool.org/manifest - /root/.cache/luarocks/http___rocks.tarantool.org_/manifest

Error: No results matching query were found for Lua 5.1.
```

Answer (score 1):

prometheus rock is deprecated

It's recomended to use more recent [tarantool/metrics](https://github.com/tarantool/metrics/) and here is an example how to use it with prometheus https://github.com/tarantool/metrics/blob/master/example/prometheus_export.lua

Comment: I have tried to install different packages from rocks, and always get error.

Comment: tarantool/tarantool image is a bundled version with a bunch of rocks on board to install additional rocks you should install additional system packages: curl, git, make etc

To resolve this particular error install curl with apk (images alpine based)